# Advise on how to structure code in relation to models in Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

In my C# backend I have classes for my entities and entity lists. When I need a function/method on that entity or entity list, I just add it to the class.

In Angular/TypeScript models are defined as interfaces in every example I come across. How should I organize the functions that operate on objects of these interfaces?

I'm using NgRx, and it is tempting to put much of this code alongside the selectors, but I feel that it will quickly become quite messy.

Answer (score 1):

The same rules apply as in C#. The models don't have to be interfaces, they can also be a class if they need to include functionality.

For example,

```
export class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string

  get fullName(): string {
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  }
}
```

However, since you're using NgRx, it's recommended to not store objects like this in the store - that's why most use interfaces.

In that case, I would create a new "selectors" file, and store the logic there to retrieve the full name. Easy to test your business logic there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes and the class keyword in Angular/typescript/(modern) javascript. A rule of thumb is to use an interface to store data (like DTO/POCO s in c#) and if you are modeling behavior use a class.

Furthermore, if you want to separate the logic, you should use delegate that to services, just like in server side frameworks like .net and spring.

A good place to start is John Pappa's angular style guide. [github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) . This has has been the de facto place to see best practices for a while now. Good luck!